# How do I convert this to an array?

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert a string that looks like this into an array of tuples

`"[(1,2), (2,3), (4,5)]"` -> `[(1,2), (2,3), (4,5)]`

Here is the body of code I would like to populate:

```
def convert_to_polygon(polygon_string):

    return polygon_array
```

Should I be using a python library? Does one exist for this job?

Comment: Tuples have `()` and lists have `[]`. The one which you have shown is called set `{}`. So, please clarify what exactly you are trying to do and what you really want.

Comment: So I want to be able to do this: polygon_array[x][0], where x is the indexed pair and [0] is the first of that pair. Would I use tuple, list or set? I'm new to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = '{{1,2},{2,3},{4,5}}'
>>> polygon_array = ast.literal_eval(s.replace('{', '(').replace('}', ')'))
>>> polygon_array
((1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 5))
>>> polygon_array[1][0]
2
```

Use `list(polygon_array)` if you want a list of tuples.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def convert_to_polygon(polygon_string):
...     return eval(polygon_string)
... 
>>> polygon_string = "[(1,2), (2,3), (4,5)]"
>>> convert_to_polygon(polygon_string)
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 5)]
```